# What's open-source commenting system are available?

Tags: php, open-source, comments

My site has several listing pages and on each page, I'd like to enable a commenting mechanism, but I want it to be as open source as humanly possible. This means full use of OpenID's, Facebook connect, etc. Does such a system exist that'll allow users to post their comments on my listing pages?

By the way, my site utilizes a LAMP architecture.

Comment: Under what definition of open source is Facebook Connect included? It's a proprietary, closed source system. Open ID is a standard, not open/closed source (it *has* no source - the various *implementations* may be open or closed source).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your use of "open-source" is confusing in this context. Facebook Connect is closed-source, and OpenID isn't *anything*-source - it's a standard, and there are both open- and closed-source implementations of that standard.

You seem to mean simply "a wide variety of authentication methods". There are oodles of plugins for OpenID/Facebook/Twitter/etc. authentication on most of the major CMSes. If you want an all-in-one system, [DISQUS](http://disqus.com/overview/) is the best I've seen. It's a pretty simple JavaScript drop-in, and has an API for exporting comments into other systems like WordPress.

Answer (score 0):

How about [YATCP](http://www.organisiert.net/yatcp/)?

Or [this one](http://meidell.dk/archives/2006/12/19/brians-threaded-comments-159/)?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar question a few weeks back. Check it out, there are self-hosted and externally-hosted solutions.

[Unobtrusive, self-hosted comments function to put onto existing web pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2053217/unobtrusive-self-hosted-comments-function-to-put-onto-existing-web-pages)