# Is there an open source Wordpress plug-in to implement Facebook/Twitter/OpenID/... authentication?

Tags: wordpress, plugins, openid, facebook

> **Possible duplicate:**
>   [What’s open-source commenting system are available?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2670197/whats-open-source-commenting-system-are-available)

Hi,
I'm looking for a way to implement Facebook/Twitter/OpenID/... authentication on my WordPress blog.

I have found plugins for Twitter, plugins for Facebook, plugins for OpenID.. but I'm afraid integration of all thos plugins will be tough.

Also, I have found RPX that is doing the job perfectly, but I would prefer an open source soultion rather than relying on RPX web service.

Would you have any clue?

Nicolas

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2670197/whats-open-source-commenting-system-are-available

Answer (score 0):

Here's another one that depends on a web service: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/gigya-socialize-for-wordpress/

It seems like this is a common thing. Integrating so many logins is complicated enough that it kind of makes sense that no one has made one plugin that handles them all.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use GIGYA for this. The site link is gigya.com

And plugin URL is : http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/gigya-socialize-for-wordpress/

Comment: I hope this helped you to accomplish your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

After several trials, the best for me is http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/social-connect/
Here you can find some details on installing it
http://giannopoulos.net/2011/12/28/how-to-add-facebooktwitteretc-authentication-on-wordpress/